google cloud vision api not working in mobile
I am using Node.js in VS Code as backhand to run google cloud vision api. Also I am using Next.js in VS Code as frontend to show the webpage. I am trying to detect the text from the image. When I use in Computer website, it works well. However if I try to use in mobile website, It gives me error. Is Mobile website environment different from computer website environment?
